# Numpy Attribute Error : Float object has no attribtue 'arctan2'

Tags: python, numpy, sympy

I have been trying to implement this piece of code but since I am very new to numpy I have less idea about this error.

```
import numpy as np
from sympy import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def asSpherical(coord):
    x=coord[0]
    y=coord[1]
    z=coord[2]
    azimuth = np.arctan2(y,x)
    elevation = np.arctan2(z,np.sqrt(x**2 + y**2))
    r = np.sqrt(x**2 + y**2 + z**2)
    return [azimuth, elevation, r]

def ecefToEnu(lamb, phi, coord_set):
    # @param1 is lattitude
    # @param2 is longitude
    # @param3 is coordinate set in form of a list

    # R matrix of size 3x3
    # This transforms the ECEF coordinates to ENU
    trans_matrix = [
        [-np.sin(lamb), np.cos(lamb), 0],
        [-(np.cos(lamb))*np.sin(phi), -
         np.sin(lamb)*np.sin(phi), np.cos(phi)],
        [np.cos(lamb)*np.cos(phi), np.sin(lamb)*np.cos(phi), sin(phi)]
    ]
    # Performs the matrix multiplication
    enu_coords = np.matmul(trans_matrix, coord_set)
    # Returns a list of Cartesian Coordinates
    sph_coords = asSpherical(enu_coords)
    return sph_coords


coord_list = []
print("Enter the latitude")
latitude = float(input())
print("Enter the coordinate list:")
print("Enter X:")
coord_list.append(float(input()))
print("Enter Y:")
coord_list.append(float(input()))
print("Enter Z:")
coord_list.append(float(input()))
phiDegSet = np.arange(-180, 180, 1)
Nset = len(phiDegSet)
t0 = np.linspace(0, 24, Nset)
t0 = list(t0)

res = []
for i in range(0, 360):
    temp_list = ecefToEnu(latitude, phiDegSet[i], coord_list)
    res.append(temp_list)
elevDegSet = []
for i in res:
    elevDegSet.append(i[1])
```

Which gives me an error:

```
    elevation = np.arctan2(z,np.sqrt(x**2 + y**2))
AttributeError: 'Float' object has no attribute 'arctan2'
```

I am already passing the value to the function as float. Even the importing numpy works fine.

Comment: what is `type(np)`?

Comment: @mozway I have written at the top of the code that `import numpy as np`  which is numpy module.

Comment: You're passing a symbolic expression to numpy's arctan2 function. You should use sympy's symbolic atan2 function. Don't pass sympy expressions into numpy functions.

Comment: @crackjack111 yes, but this wasn't my question ;) can you provide the output? If somewhere else you did `np = 1.0` you would get the exact same error (case excepted, so maybe this is no a float but a different object)

Comment: Get rid of the `sympy` import!

Comment: @mozway, I see this kind of error when the function is applied to an object dtype array.  Using a sympy symbol or expression would create such an array.

Comment: Look closely at your definition of `trans_matrix` in `ecefToEnu()`.  The last term is `sin(phi)`, *not* `np.sin(phi)`.  Because you have `from sympy import *` at the beginning of your code, you have imported the name `sin` from `sympy`.  This is a good example of why `from <whatever> import *` is generally a bad practice in Python programs.  (It can be convenient in interactive sessions, but even then, you still have to be aware of which names came from which imports.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a `print` statement right before the `arctan`:

```
def asSpherical(coord):
    x=coord[0]
    y=coord[1]
    z=coord[2]
    print(x,y,z)
    azimuth = np.arctan2(y,x)
    ...
```

and got this run:

```
....
ter the latitude
45
Enter the coordinate list:
Enter X:
45
Enter Y:
45
Enter Z:
45
-14.65116910723749 -76.54620448997258 -37.062720709188 - 45.0*sin(180)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "stack71078990.py", line 52, in <module>
    temp_list = ecefToEnu(latitude, phiDegSet[i], coord_list)
  File "stack71078990.py", line 31, in ecefToEnu
    sph_coords = asSpherical(enu_coords)
  File "stack71078990.py", line 11, in asSpherical
    elevation = np.arctan2(z,np.sqrt(x**2 + y**2))
AttributeError: 'Add' object has no attribute 'arctan2'
```

`z` is `-37.062720709188 - 45.0*sin(180)`, where `sin(180)` a `sympy` expression.

I see `sin(phi)` in the `trans_matrix` expression. Because of the `from sympy import *`, `sin` (as opposed to `np.sin`) is a `sympy` function.

Removing that import (as I commented) raises:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "stack71078990.py", line 52, in <module>
    temp_list = ecefToEnu(latitude, phiDegSet[i], coord_list)
  File "stack71078990.py", line 26, in ecefToEnu
    [np.cos(lamb)*np.cos(phi), np.sin(lamb)*np.cos(phi), sin(phi)]
NameError: name 'sin' is not defined
```

Changing that to `np.sin` (like the other functions in the definition), lets the script run without error.

Comment: I think you should stress again the dangers of `from sympy import *`

Comment: @hpaulj Thank you very much. I believe the issue was that sympy was interfering with numpy functions . When I removed the sympy import, the code was working fine. Much thanks.