# Why does numpy.arctan2 not work with ufloat?

Tags: python, numpy

Running np.arctan2 on uncertainties.ufloat objects results in an error.
"AttributeError: 'Variable' object has no attribute 'arctan2'"

[Someone else asked this question before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71078990/numpy-attribute-error-float-object-has-no-attribtue-arctan2), however, it was because of a name clash with sympy. Removing the name clash fixed the problem.

On the contrary I get the error without importing anything else. Here is the minimal code that throws me the errror if I make a new jupyter notebook with it:

```
from uncertainties import ufloat
import numpy as np

ccos = ufloat(-3.45694E-05, 1.43107E-06)
csin = ufloat(-0.000363727, 1.36989E-06)

np.arctan2(csin,ccos)
```

Throws the error

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Untitled-1.ipynb Cell 1 in ()
      4 ccos = ufloat(-3.45694E-05, 1.43107E-06)
      5 csin = ufloat(-0.000363727, 1.36989E-06)
----> 7 np.arctan2(csin,ccos)

AttributeError: 'Variable' object has no attribute 'arctan2'
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: numpy functions like this first turn their input into an `numpy array`.  My guess is that `np.array(csin)` becomes an object dtype array.  Functions applied to object dtype arrays try to find a corresponding method for each element.  While that works with operators like addition (`__add__` method), but few classes implement functions like `sin` or `arctan2` as methods.  Your link has the same problem, but with `sympy` objects in the array.

Answer (score 1):

This is most probably because `ufloat` is not a native `numpy` datatype.

You can use the provided `math` functions of `uncertainties` instead.

I have just checked the following modified code and it works:

```
from uncertainties import ufloat

from uncertainties.umath import atan2

ccos = ufloat(-3.45694E-05, 1.43107E-06)

csin = ufloat(-0.000363727, 1.36989E-06)

angle = atan2(csin, ccos)

print(angle)
```

Which outputs:

```
-1.666+/-0.004
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like numpy doesn't support the uncertainties package.

To fix the issue can just use the uncertainties package version of the math functions:

```
from uncertainties.umath import *
atan2(ufloat(-3.4, 1.4),ufloat(-2,.2))
```

(this was maybe too simple, not sure if I should delete the question)